# Notification doesn't work with variables (Android)

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

This really dumb error is very strange. I want to send a notification on a specific day with a specific time. Actual it works - when I don't use variables. To understand what I mean, just look at this code:

```
// 28.08.2019 at 00:01 AM
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 28)
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7)
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019)
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1)
```

Remember: The month begins with 0, so for the actual month I need to use **7**. As I said, with this code it works fine. But now I declare a variable for the month and for the day, so:

```
// day = 28
val dayNoti = day
// month = 8
val monthNoti = month - 1
// 28.08.2019 at 00:01 AM
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayNoti)
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNoti)
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019)
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1)
```

And it doesn't work! That's sooo annoying. I've no idea why this happen. And btw: I need to declare this variables, because the code part is in a function and I call the function multiple time with different values.

**EDIT (1):**

That's the complete function:

```
// IMPORTANT: Before I'm calling the function, I did already 'month - 1'. It's the same result: it doesn't work
fun notification(hour: Int, minute: Int, day: Int, month: Int) {
    val titleNotification: String
    val descNotification: String

    val _intent = Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    _intent.putExtra("dataNotification_title", titleNotification)
    _intent.putExtra("dataNotification_desc", descNotification)

    val randomCode = 7015

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, randomCode, _intent, 0)
    val alarmManager = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019)
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() < calendar.timeInMillis){
        timeUntilAlert = calendar.timeInMillis
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeUntilAlert, pendingIntent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: No, there is nothing @Blnpwr

Comment: "doesn't work" means exactly what?

Comment: @Henry notification not showing up

Comment: Your code is showing only a specifict section. However I would suggest you to check the calendar value in log after you set the date to it. It will help to get the issue in detail.

Comment: that (what you posted) generally "must" work, so your problem is in something you didn't post.. in similar cases posting [MCVE] may often bring correct answer faster.

Comment: @HariNJha That's the result of `println(calendar.time)`: **Wed Aug 28 00:01:00 GMT+02:00 2019**

Comment: Are you sure you have posted the exact code? Note that you set minute to 0 and second to 1 but the date shown has it the other way round.

Comment: @HariNJha It's the same code

Comment: @Ped7g I can post the complete function, but it's a simple notification, there is nothing special

Comment: Post it please, the code you have posted is correct and it should be working. The error is elsewhere, but not on your code snippet.

Comment: @Blnpwr added, check Edit (1)

Comment: Where is the `month - 1`?

Comment: There is a compilation error, u should not be able to compile this because you are missing the variable "month-1"

Comment: @Henry before I'm calling the function, I already did month - 1. It is the same result, before calling the function or in the function, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Blnpwr no, dude. read my comment to Henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "solution". Everything is fine, the error was I called the notification-function in a for-loop and I forgot to change the `randomCode` for each notification. Each function has specific values, but the `randomCode` for the `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` was the same and that is the reason why it doesn't work.

And the reason why it has worked without variables, is, because I called the function separate, without a for-loop.

However, thanks to everyone. Dumb mistake from me.